# Separate configuration from main execution in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have included requirejs with the `data-main` entry point as described [here in the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main).

```
<script data-main="js/app-main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

The *app-main.js* file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/myapp/',
    ...
});

requirejs(['main']);
```

I want to **separate the require configuration from the main execution** (to share the config between production and testing environments for example).

So basically I need an *app.js* file (with configuration only):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/myapp/',
    ...
});
```

and the *main.js* file which starts the app execution (not included in testing environment).

How can I include those two files (in the correct order) with the single `data-main` entry point?

---

I have tried with an *app-main.js* file containing `require(['app','main']);` but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ditch the data-main convenience method, and include them manually.

```
<script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script>

// Optionally set base url depending on environment.
// Otherwise could just include in app.js
require.config({baseUrl : <% baseUrl %>})

//require app config file first
require(['app'], function() {
  require(['main'])
});

</script>
```

Although this creates an extra HTTP request, if you are using the r.js optimizer, this shouldn't be a problem, as you can bundle require.js into the main config module.